# How to validate WSO2 JWT from API Manager within remote backend server?

Tags: wso2, jwt, wso2-api-manager

I would like to know an overview of what's the proper way to validate JWT at remote backend server?
I believe I'd need a public key...does API-M expose an endpoint to obtain a public key or do I extract it from wso2carbon.jks?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 API Manager signs the JWT with the private key of its keystore and you have to export it from the above keystore. We don't provide an endpoint for extracting public key.

Also, it's highly recommended to use your own keystore rather than the one shipped with WSO2 product because that keystore are common to all the products and released publically.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply!